# Bibliography error in TeXworks

Tags: bibliographies, errors, citing, texworks, cite-package

I use Latex quite well but I have only used Overleaf so I didn't have any problem. Now I've start to use TexWork editor and I have some  issues with Bibliography. I've create this basic script

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{00_system/pack}
\addbibresource{00_system/biblio.bib}

\title{Test}
\author{Brando}
\date{September 2021}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Test \cite{Huber_02}
\input{01_intro/01_intro}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The biblio.bib file contains only a references to make a test:

```
@article{Huber_02,
    doi = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.fusengdes.2013.02.053},
    month = {10},
    year = {2013},
    pages = {},
    author = {A. Huber and S. Brezinsek and Ph. Mertens},
    title = {A new radiation-hard endoscope for divertor spectroscopy on JET},
    journal = {Elsevier},
}
```

The result is

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Thank for your help and forgive me for my english :)

Comment: we can not run your example but it appears that you are using biblatex.  You need to run biber after running pdflatex, then run pdflatex again.

Comment: Using your procedure the script works perfectly. I didn't find this procedure in the manual. So I have to run using PdfLatex, then Biber ane then another time PdfLatex. Is it corect ?

Comment: Use `@` to ping a user. For bibliographies with biblatex/biber, the first latex run produces a file that will tell biber what was cited and what `.bib` files to use; the biber run (a separate program) collects and collates the information from the `.bib` files and produces a file for the next latex run to read in and populate the citations and bibliography. These steps can be automated via scripts, e.g., with `arara`, or via backend jobs of user-systems like Overleaf.